# How does compare by time price and convenience bus and flight when transiting from Cambodia to Bangkok?

Tags: transit, thailand, cambodia, bangkok, phnom-penh

Although this question might be seen as opinion based one I believe it can be answered by looking at costs of price, time and convenience...

**How does compare by time price and convenience bus and flight when transiting from Cambodia to Bangkok?**

Comment: "Better" in what way? What are your priorities, tastes, expectations, fears, budget, schedule, and other constraints? There are lots of flights and lots of buses, so clearly there is something about each that appeals to a segment of travelers.

Comment: @choster Hi choster, how often do inconveniences and higher prises appeal to you? lol, I am sure question could be rephrased... I just wanted to have a moreless detailed answer that compares crossing a border by land that would have time and price and some detail comaparisings... Would you like to help me come up with better title?

Comment: It is not about the title, it is about the scope. because yes, when I am on long-term travel I do take less "convenient" routes to save money, or for better scenery, or because I can meet more locals, or because I can meet more travelers. or because the connections are better, or because I want my money to go to different vendors, or because I want to reduce my environmental impact, or because I want to do things the way I read in a book or on my friend's postcard. Or maybe something else.

Comment: @choster Do you believe all the things you list above are relevant to average traveler? anyway I have changed the title... now there should be no misunderstandings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR; Take a flight**

I will take starting point in Cambodia Sihanoukville however there shouldn't be much difference in price and time going from Siam Reap.

Flight:

price - 95$ with Bangkok airlines one way or round-trip for around 150$ , + 11 $ bus one way ~105$ total

time - from Sihanoukville 5-6 hours + airport checks 2 hours + flight 45 minutes = ~9 hours

Trip on a bus to Phnom Penh can be made with '[Giant Ibis](http://giantibis.com/)' that has charger sockets and wifi, then it's your normal flight routine...

By bus:

price - 28$ ticket with '[virak buntham](http://www.virakbuntham.com/)' + 60$  VOA if you need one + 5$ at Thai border guy will arrange a minibus that will get you further into the country + ~10$ other expenses if you are coming without fully prepared documents
45$-105$

time: 5-6 hours to border, 1-2 hours to cross the border, 0-1 hours to find minibus, 5-9 hours to get to Bangkok 12-18 hours

convenience: if you are up for scenery on Cambodian side bus goes trough some mountain and ocean views, bus does not have wifi nor sockets, if you do not have all the documents ready like: passport copy (they don't do a copy there and then you have to bring it with yourself), your **printed** flight tickets showing on 
 mobile does not cut it, photo, and 2000 THB (they do not accept dollars nor change them at the border so you have to go to town to get them changed), you will be going back to Cambodian side taking a bike for 5$ and then going to print shop and printing copies for ~3$, exchange rate for 2000 THB I got was 62$... I had photo ready but I would assume it will be x2 normal so 3-5$...

All and all I am happy that I took bus as it was an experience, however I consider myself to be resilient and somewhat stress prone, for some it might be a bit too much to do the border crossing by land from Thailand to Cambodia (I saw girl crying, lol), and since it takes less time and costs about the same (for someone who needs VOA) I would recommend taking a flight...

Comment: Particularly for those who do `not` live near the border of those countries, then flight is usually less overall hassle.  But yes, this question will attract discussion and debate by its very nature :(